# Finding the average of a list within a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have created a dictionary called **'alt_dict'** within which I am looking to average the values within each respective list.

```
import statistics
datas = [['CC',      1,     0,     0,      0,    2.5],
         ['CC',      1,   4.5,     0,    4.5,    2.8],
         ['CC',      1,   9.5,     0,    9.5,    2.5],
         ['CC',      2,     0,   2.5,      0,      5],
         ['CC',      2,   4.5,   2.8,    4.5,      5],
         ['CC',      2,   9.5,   2.5,    9.5,      5],
         ['CC',      3,     0,     5,      0,    7.5],
         ['CC',      3,   4.5,     5,    4.5,    7.2],
         ['CC',      3,   9.5,     5,    9.5,    7.9]]
cc_list = []
alt_dict = {}

for i in range(len(datas)):
    if datas[i][0] == 'CC':
        cc_list.append(datas[i][1])
cc_list_plane = list(set(cc_list))

for y in cc_list_plane:
    alt_dict[y] = []

for i in range(len(datas)):
    if datas[i][0] == 'CC':
        key = datas[i][1]
        alt_dict[key].extend([datas[i][5]-datas[i][3]])
#        alt_dict[key].extend([statistics.mean(datas[i][5]-datas[i][3])])
print(alt_dict)
```

What I'm looking for is the following:

```
{1: [2.6], 2: [2.4], 3: [2.5333]}
```

I have tried using the **'statistics'** library with its **'mean'** function, but I get a TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable.

Is there a solution for this type of case? Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
res = {k: [sum(v)/len(v)] for k, v in alt_dict.items()}
```

**Output:**

```
{1: [2.6], 2: [2.4], 3: [2.5333333333333337]}
```

Using `statistics.mean()`

```
res = {k: [statistics.mean(v)] for k, v in alt_dict.items()}
#{1: [2.6], 2: [2.4], 3: [2.5333333333333337]}
```

Answer (score 1):

- The current implementation is inefficient because it requires multiple iterations over `datas` to create the keys and to fill `alt_dict`, plus an iteration to create `alt_dict`.
- The following implementation does everything with a single loop and returns the desired output.

  - Relies on the [`.get()`](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/#built-in-dictionary-methods) to check for the existence of a key

```py
from statistics import mean

alt_dict = dict()
for v in datas:
    if v[0] == 'CC':
        value = [v[5] - v[3]]
        if alt_dict.get(v[1]) == None:
            alt_dict[v[1]] = value
        else:
            alt_dict[v[1]].extend(value)

alt_dict = {k: mean(v) for k, v in alt_dict.items()}

print(alt_dict)

>>> {1: 2.6, 2: 2.4, 3: 2.5333333333333337}
```

### As a function:

```py
def list_calcs(data: list, key: str, col1: int, col2: int) -> dict:
    """
    data: list of lists
    key: str of interest in data[0][0] -> 'CC'
    col1: data[0][col1]
    col2: data[0][col2]
    data[0][col1] - data[0][col2]
    """
    alt_dict = dict()
    for v in data:
        if v[0] == key:
            value = [v[col1] - v[col2]]
            if alt_dict.get(v[1]) == None:
                alt_dict[v[1]] = value
            else:
                alt_dict[v[1]].extend(value)

    return {k: mean(v) for k, v in alt_dict.items()}

alt_dict = list_calcs(datas, 'CC', 5, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable input and observations, best regards @Trenton McKinney.